# SKView not showing in single view application

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Trying to implement a game into my single view application. I followed the steps of adding the Spritekit.framework into my application. Then I tried to add SKView into my viewcontroller's custom class but Xcode 7 doesn't seem to like that so the module part is blank. Then after compiling I always crash on:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[SKView]'

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var spriteView: SKView = self.view as! SKView
        spriteView.showsDrawCount = true
        spriteView.showsNodeCount = true
        spriteView.showsFPS = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: @BeauYoung in terms of what code? The code I wrote is some basic fps testing. The error?

Comment: Show us how you're trying to add the SKView to your view controller.

Comment: @BeauYoung can you see with the update?

Comment: In your file inspector on the left it isn't showing SpriteKit.framework as added or modified. Which is odd. You sure it is linked to your project correctly?

Comment: Actually just noticed your problem I will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice it at first but you are assigning SKView class to a UIViewController. You will want to switch it to your ViewController class and then go down to view and change that to SKView.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting code.

First up. You're creating the SKView from a UIView. I think you may have pulled this from a new SpriteKit template? If you check the Storyboard for the template, I think you'll find that the view that has been added to the controller is an SKView.

Changing this in your storyboard to an SKView will solve your issue, however the base view of your controller will now be an SKView, and you may or may not want that.

Alternatively you can add your SKView as a subview:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var spriteView = SKView(frame: view.frame)
        spriteView.showsDrawCount = true
        spriteView.showsNodeCount = true
        spriteView.showsFPS = true
        view.addSubview(spriteView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure with var spriteView: SKView()

Comment: Was just to see if you were getting the same crash, updated so you can set the frame.

Comment: var spriteView: SKView(frame: view.frame) hmm